# How to pass hashmap as payload in RES and how to test it through POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a rest API with the following URL

```
@PostMapping(path = "/Employees/employees")
private ResponseEntity<Map<String, BigDecimal>> availabilityCalculator(@RequestBody ReqOb req, Map<String, BigDecimal> testMap) {}
```

> what annotation should I use for the map(like RequestBody for Object). Can I use RequestBody itself considering the map is also a type of object? 2. How should I pass - a hashmap and an object as payload for testing it through POSTMAN

Comment: what do you mean "how to use it as rest" ? What's your problem? Do you need to start it in an jax/rs container, or how to access it via http?

Comment: @fairtrax
1. what annotation should I use for the map(like RequestBody for Object). Can I use RequestBody itself considering the map is also a type of object?
2. How should I pass - a hashmap and an object as payload for testing it through POSTMAN

Comment: You should wrap it. String is a object also but you are also wrapping it. Create a class that contains that Map and pass it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that will contain that map and pass it like that. For example:

```
public class CalculationStatsDto {

  private Map<String, BigDecimal> testMap;

  public CalculationStatsDto () {

  }

  public Map<String, BigDecimal> getTestMap() {
      return testMap;
  }

  public void setTestMap(Map<String, BigDecimal> testMap) {
      this.testMap = testMap;
  }
}
```

And your rest method should be:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/Employees/employees")
private ResponseEntity<CalculationStatsDto> availabilityCalculator(@RequestBody 
CalculationStatsDto calculationStatsDto) {}
```

And if you need also that 'ReqOb req' in the request body then you can put it in your entity class:

```
public class CalculationStatsDto {

private Map<String, BigDecimal> testMap;

private ReqOb req;

public CalculationStatsDto() {

}

public Map<String, BigDecimal> getTestMap() {
    return testMap;
}

public void setTestMap(Map<String, BigDecimal> testMap) {
    this.testMap = testMap;
}

public ReqOb getReq() {
    return req;
}

public void setReq(ReqOb req) {
    this.req = req;
}
}
```

With the last one you will wrap both of it in one request body.